# Can't access Ubuntu desktop from RDP

Tags: 16.04, xrdp, rdp

The RDP screen i.e; the remote Ubuntu desktop displayed a grey screen and the RDP windows closed, just can't connect.

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide a lot of details about your configuration. are you running Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10, 17.04 ?  Are you using Unity Desktop or Gnome or LXDE ?

Each Ubuntu version and flavors needs to be configured a little bit differently to have xRDP working.....

You could try the following to get started (see http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952). In this procedure, you will need to install a alternate desktop (mate desktop) and you should have access remotely to your system...

To summarize,

Install xrdp

- **sudo apt-get install xrdp**

Install mate desktop

- **sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon**

Configure your .xsession file by issuing the following command

- **echo mate-session >~/.xsession**

Configure your Keyboard layout

- Please review the [post](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=895) for this configuration aspect

and give it a try

If you want to use the default Unity Desktop, let us know and we could provide necessary information....

Hope this help

Till next time 
See ya